# PHP store multi-dimensional array's key in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

It's an interesting situation for getting the array key in multi-dimensional array.

I know how to get the array value by using foreach but how to get the key value and insert into database??

Here is my code:

```
   //Array
   $BookingInfo = array(
            "115"=>array(
                "date"=>array(
                    "15/12/2014"=>array(//need to get the date but not in here
                        array(
                            //need to get the date in here!!
                            "from"=>2,
                            "to"=>5,
                            "user"=>"Ella",
                            "userid"=>"b2111"
                                ),
                        array(
                            "from"=>5,
                            "to"=>7,
                            "user"=>"Johnson",
                            "userid"=>"a2413"
                                )   
                        ),
                    "16/12/2014"=>array(
                        array(
                            "from"=>4,
                            "to"=>8,
                            "user"=>"Peter",
                            "userid"=>"g531"
                                )
                        ),
                     "17/12/2014"=>array(
                        array(
                            "from"=>1,
                            "to"=>3,
                            "user"=>"Chris",
                            "userid"=>"h024"
                                ),
                        array(
                            "from"=>3,
                            "to"=>6,
                            "user"=>"Jennifer",
                            "userid"=>"f314"
                                )
                        ),
                    "20/12/2014"=>array(
                        array(
                            "from"=>1,
                            "to"=>5,
                            "user"=>"Raymond",
                            "username"=>"r362"
                                )
                        ),
                    "21/12/2014"=>array(
                        array(
                            "from"=>1,
                            "to"=>6,
                            "user"=>"Amy",
                            "username"=>"a754"
                                )
                        ),
                    "23/08/2014"=>array(
                        array(
                            "from"=>2,
                            "to"=>4,
                            "user"=>"Amy",
                            "userid"=>"m432"
                                )
                        )
                    )
                )
        );
```

The foreach code:

```
    foreach($BookingInfo as $roomNumber => $value){
        foreach($value as $id => $val){
            foreach($val as $bookDate => $array){
                foreach($array as $key => $detail){
                    foreach($detail as $period =>$info){
                        //get the $bookDate here
                        //if I get the "$bookDate" here, it shows the result with repeating 3 times, how can I solve it??   
                    }
                }
            }
        }                   
    }
```

And I want to get the "15/12/2014" 2 times because of two members' booking, and the "16/12/2014" 1 times, what is the method to do it? Thanks for help.

Comment: Thanks Verhaeren. Is it foreach($BookingInfo[$roomNumber][$id] as $bookDate => $array) at the third foreach?? Thank you.

Comment: Verhaeren, I have been updated the array. Thank you.

Comment: @Verhaeren, what's wrong with using ```foreach($value as $id => $val){``` ?  It's much easier to read than your suggestion.  And the 2 are equivalent, provided you're only reading from the array.

If you're concerned about modifications to the array, then it's much cleaner to assign by reference, ie change the 1st foreach to be ```foreach($BookingInfo as $roomNumber => &$value) {```, but I don't think that's a requirement for this particular usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to just add the bookDate to the detail array, in the second innermost loop:

```
foreach($BookingInfo as $roomNumber => $value){
    foreach($value as $id => $val){
        foreach($val as $bookDate => $array){
            foreach($array as $key => $detail){
                $detail['bookDate'] = $bookDate;
                foreach($detail as $detailkey =>$detailval){
                    print "$detailkey => $detailval\n"; 
                }
                print "***\n";
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

(Just make sure that whatever key you use isn't one that might be in the details array already or you might cause some confusion).

See http://codepad.org/oQT3cmo8 for output

Comment: Thanks lucas, but I have a problem that why the results will repeat 5 times by using var_dump($detail["bookDate"])?? Also I need to collect the array into function but it does 5 times of each value......How can I solve it, or should I call the function outside the foreach? Thank you very much, lucas.

Comment: Where are you putting the ```var_dump($detail["bookDate"])```?  If it's in the innermost loop, then it's going to be printed once for each detail.